# Integrating a download manager to PHP script

Tags: php, firefox, download, download-manager

I'm using PHP and my script outputs a list of links for files that can be downloaded by the user. To download each file, as a user I would have to copy the url and paste it into something like Free Download Manager.

I would like to improve the user experience and have a "Download" button that would handle or initiate the download process.

I'm thinking either have code written in PHP to act as a download manager, or tie the "Download" button to the functionality of a firefox or such add-on that act as a download manager. Does anyone have good suggestions for the sort of thing I'm trying to do?

---

Update:

Let's say that:
- my script presents the user with a list of files that can be downloaded. 
- next to each file, there's a checkbox, then at the bottom a button that says "download selected".

If this is the setup I have, if I use force download, then clicking the "download selected" button will force dl 12 files at the same time, so not exactly like a download manager. I'm thinking this probably requires something that takes both PHP and Firefox behavior into account.

Comment: Unless a specific download manager implements a concrete download list format, there's no way to automate a "list of urls to download" mechanism.

Comment: @mario, Can you tell me more. Also read my updated question.

Comment: Not possible. MIME allows for multipart/ payloads and external url entities, but not for HTTP clients. At best you could pop up multiple iframes (or a JS Location:/Refresh: chain) and force 12 download dialogs at once. That's not very reliable and user-friendly. So unless you *already have* decided on a workable Firefox download extension which provides an option for that, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to force download for single file per time and multiple times.

Some links for you to reference from.

- http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/12/how-to-force-file-download-with-php/
- http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download

Another good example from php.net: [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: careful with IE, it disrespects the Content-Type header in up to IE7, and also in IE8 when in quirks mode.

Comment: I don't know about this, do you have any sources related to this?

Comment: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/wrongWithIE/?chapter=Content-type%3A+text%2Fplain here's one.  Try it in the older versions of IE.  There's another one about it (it actually led to security issues), lemme dig it up.

Comment: @BeingSimpler: here's the other link: http://blog.phpbb.com/2008/10/25/attachment-headaches-with-the-internet-explorer/ - you had to actually set a header to tell IE to behave properly  with Content-Type in IE8 still, even.  Ugh.

Comment: @BeingSimpler, But let's say that my script presents the user with a list of files that can be downloaded. Next to each file, there's a checkbox, then at the bottom a button that says "download selected". If this is the setup I have, and I use your suggestion, then clicking the "download selected" button will force dl 12 files at the same time, so not exactly like a download manager. I'm thinking this probably requires something that takes both PHP and Firefox behavior into account.

Comment: So you are talking about download manager (this could be browser's add-on rather than web app itself). I think it isn't so related to PHP since PHP can only handle one-by-one downloads, or this is out of my knowledge range. I know there is a Java Applet that helps users download multiple files called myDownloader: http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/download-systems/